# How to wrap the VideoOverlay component in react-leaflet with a div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v4

I'm currently working on integrating a video overlay onto a map using the `react-leaflet` library. I'm using the `VideoOverlay` component provided by `react-leaflet` to render the video onto the map successfully. However, I also need to display an arrow pointing from the video to a specific location on the map.

The challenge I'm facing is that the [VideoOverlay](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/main/src/layer/VideoOverlay.js) component only renders the `video` HTML element, and I'm unsure how to add a sibling `div` alongside it to display the arrow.

Is there a way to wrap the [VideoOverlay](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components/#videooverlay) component in a containing `div` and add another sibling `div` for displaying the arrow? Alternatively, is there a recommended approach or workaround to achieve this functionality while using react-leaflet?

Any guidance on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! I am having a go at creating a custom component using the [factory methods in the react-leaflet core API](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/core-api/#high-level-component-factories)